# sudo asks me for password

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

i edited /etc/sudoers using visudo command so as to grant user sudo privilege without password as following :

```
userName ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

but it didn't work for me ,

any suggestions 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you use visudo to edit the file. Are you sure your config is valid?

Comment: What does the output of `sudo -l` look like while logged in as `userName`?

Comment: @Zoredache i used visudo , what do you mean with valid config ?

Comment: @KyleSmith :Matching Defaults entries for emamdouh on this host:
    env_reset

User emamdouh may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL : ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
    (ALL) ALL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that no rule below your mentioned rule are overriding it. From `man sudoers` (1.7.2p2):

```
   When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order.
   Where there are multiple matches, the last match is used (which is not
   necessarily the most specific match).
```

Comment: you are right as output of sudo -l shows that there are two rules applied to that user

Answer (score 0):

try

```
userName ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: Please expand on your answer (*why* should they try this? *what does it do?*) -- See http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/06/09/press-the-green-button-twice/

Comment: nope, this wasn't the problem, the problem was that there was two rules applied to that user